# Is there any way to type annotate a parameter must be part of an interface

Tags: typescript

I have the following function

```
export const getCreateProductsError = (index: number, err: string) => createSelector(
  getCreateFeatureState,
  state => state.productsError.getIn([index, err])
)
```

now I would like err to be one of the keys I have in my interface

```
export interface IProductError {
  isPriceError: boolean;
  isAmountError: boolean;
  isDescriptionError: boolean;
}
```

is there any way to annotate that instead of string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type operator you are looking for is literally named after your problem: you want the type to be a "key of" `IProductError`, and the operator is named [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator).

```typescript
export const getCreateProductsError = (index: number, err: keyof IProductError) =>
  createSelector(
    getCreateFeatureState,
    state => state.productsError.getIn([index, err])
  )
```

`keyof` produces a [*union*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of [*literal types*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) corresponding to all the keys, i.e. `keyof IProductError` is equivalent to `"isPriceError" | "isAmountError" | "isDescriptionError"`.